# In Bootstrap, how to avoid a row to collapse when there is no content inside?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lametaweb/h7ou56Lf/) there is an example showing my problem. When I leave the colum empty the row colapses. What I want is the row does not colapse even when it is empty. How could I achieve this?

The code:

JS

```
$(function(){
  $("button").on("click",function(){
    $("#here").text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:black">
       <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="color:brown; background:red">
           <span id="here" style="font-size:2em;"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button>yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to declare a height if there is no content.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:black; height: 40px;">
       <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="color:brown; background:red">
           <span id="here" style="font-size:2em;"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button>yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@AmyBarrett, thanks for your answer. I was looking for a solution with no additional settings. Finally I opted for replacing the `<span>` tag with an `<input>` tag, which correspond to an HTML empty element in the DOM, retaining its height even when empty.